# Error on simple javascript function using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have this small function giving an error because `i is undefined`:

```
var i = 0
    setInterval(function(i){
        var i = ( i < $(".news-items li").length ) ? i++ : 0 ;
        $(".news-items li").hide();
        $(".news-items li:eq("+i+")").show();
    }, 1000)
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(i){
```

You're redeclaring `i` as a local variable in the anonymous function.  Remove the `i` in the function's parameter list.

```
var i = 0
setInterval(function(){
    // Note that this will NOT update the global "i"
    // if you want it to, remove "var"
    // Also change "i++' to "i+1"
    var i = ( i < $(".news-items li").length ) ? i+1 : 0 ;
    $(".news-items li").hide();
    $(".news-items li:eq("+i+")").show();
}, 1000)
```